# Select between entities using relationships in SparQL

Tags: sparql, owl, semantic-web

i have two entities Director and Movie and between them there is a relation ship called isDirectorOf for example a director isDirectorOf a certain movie so i want i my sparql query to look for directors who made that movie here is what i wrote but it didn't work am new in sparql and i didn't know how to solve this problem

```
PREFIX ns: <http://www.owl-ontologies.com/ProjetSemantique.owl#>
 PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>



   SELECT ?Director 
      WHERE
       {   
         ?Director rdf:type ns:Director .
         ?Director ?isDirectorOf "Interstellar" .
             }
```

i didn't know how to do this right

Comment: `"Interstellar"` looks like a literal, which should probably be a URI. Without seeing your data, or having access to your SPARQL endpoint, answers will necessarily be vague. (Note that there are many similar questions on this site, which may help you figure some things out. )

Comment: yes i put interstellar myself just to try if the query works fine or not

Comment: @TallTed can you help me this please am stuck so hard ...

Comment: Start with these...  https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=director+movie+sparql

Comment: @AOUADISlim what is the URI of the movie entity? Or is this really just a literal? How did you create and add the data to your triple store? Does the literal have a language tag? If you did it with Protege, I'm pretty sure it is not just a literal, but some proper RDF entity identified by a URI. But that's just a guess. So, edit your question show your raw RDF data here. Ideally, you N-Triples or Turtle format for your data